# Flyway with Postgres on migration failure

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I consider to use Flyway with postgresql.

When a migration fails do I need to manually roll it back or does it work ootb with postgres?
Do following migrations continue to ran after a failed one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway uses PostgreSQL's support for DDL transactions.

The migration is rolled back and the migration process stops.